# How to implement screensharing in IOS app using OpenTok

Tags: ios, swift, opentok, tokbox

I am working on an IOS app, in which i have implemented Video call using OpenTok SDK and its working, now i need to implement screen sharing using openTok SDK.

To implement that, i have given following lines in publisher's doPublish() method.

publisher.videoType = .screen

publisher.audioFallbackEnabled = false

but still screen is not getting shared instead of that camera is enabled.

I have followed the steps given in this link https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/screen-sharing/ios/

Can any one help?

Answer (score 0):

To share your screen you need to use a custom video capturer.

> To use the device's screen, instead of a camera, as the video source, use the PublisherKit class to use a custom video capturer. For a code sample, see the Screen-Sharing project in the samples directory of the SDK. https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/screen-sharing/ios/

We have a sample application with screen sharing implemented where you can find a class for you to use:

[Swift](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-ios-sdk-samples-swift/tree/master/Screen-Sharing)

[Objc-C](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-ios-sdk-samples/tree/master/Screen-Sharing)

Comment: Hi, I am able to test the 'screen-sharing' sample by running this app in iphone and able to see output screen in opentok playground. Can you guide to test the same without playground? In my app i have to implement screen sharing with Video Call, how to combine both?

Comment: To do both, copy the `ScreenCapturer` class to your project or implement your own custom video capturer. Then add a `ScreenCapturer` object to your publisher using the `videoCapture` property. https://github.com/opentok/opentok-ios-sdk-samples-swift/blob/ceeda21e532e2eb864ee8b0c5566607f9998c1e2/Screen-Sharing/Screen-Sharing/ViewController.swift#L85

Comment: Hi, I have copied ScreenCapturer class in Basic-Video-Chat project and  in doPublish() I have added these lines and tested with OpenTok playground, but not able to see the screen. publisher.videoType = .screen
        publisher.audioFallbackEnabled = false
        capturer = ScreenCapturer(withView: view)
        publisher.videoCapture = capturer
        session.publish(publisher, error: &error)

Comment: Here is a demo project showing how to start a screen share. Run a `pod install` after cloning https://github.com/abdulajet/opentok-screenshare-demo

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for the sample but when the publisher share his screen subscriber should be able see publisher's screen but in this sample publisher's screen is getting displayed again in publisher's screen. Can you guide to proceed.

Comment: I think that is due to the fact that the entire current view controller's view is being shared. If you change the view being shared in `let cap = ScreenCapturer(withView: view)` you should have the desired outcome

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your help. 
Subscriber needs to see the whole screen of the publisher during screen sharing. When Publisher clicks on ScreenShare button there is no change in subscriber's screen. What should we do to see the publisher's shared screen in Subscriber screen.  

To test screen sharing, I am using iPhone as publisher and simulator as subscriber, is it correct way to test?

Comment: I have updated the project on the GitHub (https://github.com/abdulajet/opentok-screenshare-demo). In the new project, there is no publishing happening. When you click on "Share screen" it only publishes the whole screen to the subscriber. I have made the views different colour to illustrate it better.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your support. By referring this sample project I am able to proceed with screensharing. During VideoCall when publisher starts share screening, subscriber is able to see Publisher's screen in the bottom of his screen, in the top of his screen subscriber's view is still there. Whenever we click on Share Screen Button, we need to hide publisher's view and subscriber's view on both sides. how can we do that?

Comment: You can keep a reference to the UIView and show/hide them or you can use `session.unpublish` to unpublish publishers as needed.

Comment: Hi, In publisher side I am able to hide the view using publisher.view?.isHidden = true and able to unpublish using session.unpublish(publisher); but In Subscriber side not able to hide the view  or unpublish. How to achieve that?

Comment: Sessions have a similar `session.unsubscribe` function. In the above project there is a variable for the subscriber (`var subscriber: OTSubscriber?`) which also has a UIView property. So you can call `subscriber.view` as well

Comment: Hi, Already I have given these lines(publisher.view?.isHidden = true, subscriber?.view?.isHidden = true) inside ScreenShare Buttons’s IBAction.

Which hides publisher.view &  subscriber.view in publisher’s screen(since publisher is clicking the button) 

But in Subscriber’s side, subscriber’s view is there at the first half(which needs to be hided) of the screen. Tried with session.unsubscribe(subscriber) also but no change.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to give more clarity on my doubt. During Video call when client-1 starts sharing a screen, client-2 should see the full screen of client-1. but in my app, client-2 screen has his view at the first half of the screen and client-1's view at the second half.  Using session.unpublish & session.unsubscribe I am able to change client-1's screen but no change on client-2's screen. How to unpublish on client-2's screen when client-1 share his screen?

Comment: The size of the subscriber view is set on this line: https://github.com/abdulajet/opentok-screenshare-demo/blob/9e2726252252380ee227c08db5cc0675c94d440d/Basic-Video-Chat/ViewController.swift#L187

To make it full screen, remove `-  kWidgetHeight` from the line. This is just a normal `UIView` so you can size it via autolayout or a storyboard